# Add a class to first li if last li contains class

Tags: jquery

There is a class that is being added to the li on hover [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6PfKb/9/).

I want to be able to add a class to the first li if the last li has the .on class applied to it. I have tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work?

```
if ($("li.top-level:last").contains(document.on))
   {
        $('li.top-level:first').addClass('first');
   }
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/6PfKb/21/) with suggested answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Demo based on your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6PfKb/22/)

```
var $link = $('ul.internal-dropdown li.top-level');
$link.hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('on');
    if( $(this).is('li.top-level:last-child') ) {
        $('li.top-level:first').addClass('first');
    }

}, function() {
    $link.removeClass('on');
    $('li.top-level:first').removeClass('first');
});
```

---

jQuery doesn't have a `.contains()` method; but it does have a [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass) method (which does what the name suggests):

```
if( $('li.top-level:last').hasClass('on') ) {
    $('li.top-level:first').addClass('first');
}
```

Comment: Note that the jQuery utility methods (including `$.contains`) can't be referenced by elements in a matched set, they serve a completely different purpose

Comment: thanks for the tips with the hasClass, I have made the changes but I still can't get this working?  Any ideas why? I don't get any js errors but no first class seems to be added?

Comment: Do you have an updated fiddle? Remember the `on` class is removed at the end of the hover so this function would have to be called while the cursor is still hovering

Comment: I have added an updated fiddle to my question. In this fiddle I have given the first class a background of red so it makes it easier to see but it doesn't seem to be adding the class even if i leave my mouse on the last li?

Comment: @ak85 I've made the update to your fiddle, take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/6PfKb/22/

Comment: @ak85 You could also just paste my original code inside the hover function, but it's cheaper to use `this` (and check if it's last) than re-selecting the last element each time